# Final build macOs, iOS, CoreData and iCloud without AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode9

I was searching but didn’t found the right answer here.
How can I make a final build to distribute of a macOS and an iOS App including CoreData and iCloud without using the AppStore?
An installation bundle that cotains everything.
thanks for your help.
best,
pascal

Comment: How do you intend to distribute the iOS app without using the app store?

Comment: macOS should be possible. There are many companies selling their product without the App Store.

Comment: Is there no way without app store? How do you handle all the Apps you write just for friends or for your company and you don't want to provide them to the whole world? macOS should be possible. Sorry I have a Microsoft background and in the past it was very easy to just write some small apps and use them everywhere. There were programms like install shield etc for more complex installation bundles.

Comment: Yes, For macOS you just create an archive from the Product menu and then export for direct distribution from the Organizer window.  You can then distribute the app to whoever you like.  iOS is different; You can use TestFlight to distribute for testing or you can get your friends device UUIDs and build an ad-hoc version for them, but these versions will expire and they will need to re-install periodically.  Companies can get an enterprise developer membership and then distribute apps that are created under that membership to their own users using a web site or MDM.